# Firebase How to get value from reference

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So what happens is my user creates an account a key/value was stored on the realtime database now  then logs in i now need to retrieve that value but the value does not change after being created. Is there a direct way for me to get the value from key or is this not even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer i can achieve this if i use addListenerForSingleValueEvent on a reference to the key Hope this helps anyone asking the same question